# Spring @Bean configuration with constructor injection

Tags: java, spring

While Executing below code, Spring Says "The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:"

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    private final Object object1;

    public Config(@Qualifier("object1") Object object1) {
        this.object1 = object1;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("object1")
    public String getName() {
        return object1.toString();
    }

    @Bean(name = "object1")
    public Object getObject() {
       return new Object();
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me, How this form a cycle ?

Comment: How can you inject your `object1` into the constructor of a class, and then expect that configuration to create object1?

Comment: Actually i want to understand the invocation order which cause the cyclic dependency

Answer (score 1):

The `Config` class itself is a bean, which depends on your `object1` bean, and which provides your `object1` bean. (The error messages doesn't just say "some of the beans", you're getting a detailed list.)

tl;dr avoid injecting beans into configuration classes like this and make them `@Bean` method parameters instead.